# Dynamo db will not allow data to be inserted into table unless the value contains the primary key set during table creation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

The dynamo db will not allow data to be inserted into table unless the value contains the primary key set during table creation.

Dynamodb table:

```
id (primary key)
device_id
temperature_value
```

I am sending data from IoT core rule engine into the Dynamodb (Split message into multiple columns of a DynamoDB table (DynamoDBv2)). However, data does not arrive at the dynamo db table if the msg is missing the id attribute.

Is there any way to set primary key to be auto incrementing every time a new data point arrives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DynamoDB does not support auto incrementing functionality for keys as it might have in a relational database.

Instead this will need to be generated by you at the time of inserting the record into DynamoDB.

There are a few options to generate:

- Use a primary key combined of partition key (referencing your sensor id) and a sort key (something such as an event time, or a randomly generated string).
- Generate a random string instead and insert this.
- Use a seperate data store such as relational or Redis, where you autoincrement a value and use this. **This is really not ideal**.
- Use a seperate DynamoDB table to include this value ensuring you use a [transactional write](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/transactions.html) to lock the row and increment, and strongly consistent read to get the latest value. **Again this is not ideal**

Comment: Thanks, how about kinesis or timestream database? Would that be ideal?

Comment: Timestream is great for sensor data, kinesis is a streaming service so it will always need to be consumed to a permanent data store :)

Comment: Ok by default kinesis doesn't have a storage/database?

Comment: Kinesis is a stream based service, the data held is ephemeral so it will disappear after a timespan. It is also not queryable directly, you read the data in the order it was added. You generally consume it and put it in a permanent store